Editing multirow tables in Latex
Below is my code with which I have repeatedly attempted to replicate the attached table. The resulting table looks fine except for the last row, which has "Uresectable disease" as its first entry. How can I correct my code to get the correct output? I am using TexStudio with

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\geometry{margin=1in}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \centering
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}
        \begin{tabular}{|p{2.5cm}|p{3cm}|p{4.5cm}|p{5cm}|}
            \hline
            \textbf{Stage (TNM)} & \textbf{Initial Management} & \textbf{Post-operative Management} & \textbf{Follow-up} \\ 
            \hline
            \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Non-metastatic disease}} \\ 
            \hline
            {Stage I (T1 or T2, N0, M0)} & Surgery & None & Annual visit or telephonic consultation to investigate for symptoms. \\ %\cline{2-4}
            %& \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{} \\ 
            \hline
            Low-risk Stage II (T3 or T4 or T4b, N0, M0) & Surgery & None & Same as Stage I \\ 
            \hline
            High-risk Stage II & Surgery & Adjuvant chemotherapy & Visits every nine weeks for 36 weeks following surgery or completion of adjuvant disease. Repeat CT scan and colonoscopy three years post-surgery. Annual visits for five years after that. \\ 
            \hline
            Stage III (T1-4, N1-2b, M0) & Surgery & Adjuvant chemotherapy & Same as high-risk Stage II \\ 
            \hline
            \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Metastatic disease}} \\ 
            \hline
            Resectable disease & Surgery immediately or after perioperative or conversion chemotherapy & Adjuvant chemotherapy if no perioperative or conversion chemotherapy &  \\ 
            \hline
            %{Unresectable disease: Performance status 0-2: Performance status $\geq$ 3:} & \multicolumn{2}{|p{3cm}|}{None} Palliative chemotherapy &  \\ \cline{2-4}
            %& \multicolumn{2}{|p{3cm}|}{ Supportive management} &  \\ 
            %\hline
            \multicolumn{1}{|p{2.5cm}|}{Unresectable disease: \newline Performance status 0-2} & \multicolumn{2}{|p{7.5cm}|}{Palliative chemotherapy} & \\ 
            %\hline
            \multicolumn{1}{|p{2.5cm}|}{Unresectable disease: \newline Performance status $\geq$ 3} & \multicolumn{2}{|p{7.5cm}|}{Supportive management} & \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{TNM Staging and Management Summary}
    \end{table}
\end{document}


Welcome. // Please provide the few missing lines which will make your code snippet compile when we copy it. Thank you

Some vertical adjustments vary in some cells. Does this convey a certain meaning, or is it just the result of, for example, making a cells horizontal rule invisible? See my sketch here for details: https://i.sstatic.net/pC14I5fg.png

@MS-SPO, I added the lines. Thank you. The white spaces dont necessarily convey any meaning they are just misaligned in MS word.

The width of the tabular enviroment exceeds \textwidth. What's the reason for \setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}?

I tried to exactly replicate your image:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \centering
        \begin{tblr}{
            colspec={p{2.5cm}p{3cm}X[l]X[l]},
            vlines,
            hline{1-4,6-W,Y-Z}={},
            hline{5}={2-Z}{},
            hline{X}={1}{},
            row{1-2}={font=\bfseries}
            }
            Stage (TNM) & {Initial\\ Management} & {Post-operative\\ Management} & Follow-up \\ 
            \SetCell[c=4]{} Non-metastatic disease \\ 
            {Stage I (T1 or T2, N0, M0)} & Surgery & None & Annual visit or telephonic consultation to investigate for symptoms. \\ 
            Low-risk Stage II (T3 or T4 or T4b, N0, M0) & Surgery & None & Same as Stage I \\ 
            High-risk Stage II & Surgery & Adjuvant chemotherapy & Visits every nine weeks for 36 weeks following surgery or completion of adjuvant disease. Repeat CT scan and colonoscopy three years post-surgery. Annual visits for five years after that. \\ 
            Stage III (T1-4, N1-2b, M0) & Surgery & Adjuvant chemotherapy & Same as high-risk Stage II \\ 
            \SetCell[c=4]{font=\bfseries} Metastatic disease \\ 
            Resectable disease & Surgery immediately or after perioperative or conversion chemotherapy & Adjuvant chemotherapy if no perioperative or conversion chemotherapy &  \\ 
            Unresectable disease: & & & \SetCell[r=3]{} \\ 
            Performance status 0-2 & None &  Palliative chemotherapy \\ 
            Performance status $\geq$ 3 & None & Supportive management \\
        \end{tblr}
        \caption{TNM Staging and Management Summary}
    \end{table}
\end{document}



The table you're trying to replicate has a rather sloppily executed layout. I don't think it's worth your time -- in terms of informing your own readers -- to replicate it exactly.
I would also switch from tabular to tabularx, to assure that the table actually fits inside the textblock.

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' column type
\usepackge{ragged2e}  % for '\RaggedRight' macro
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for '\nobreakdash' macro
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}

\hyphenation{chemo-ther-apy peri-oper-ative}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht!]
    %\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{3pt} % for a more open "look"
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt} % why 8pt??

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|P{2.5cm}|P{3cm}|P{3.25cm}|L|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Stage (TNM)} & 
    \textbf{Initial management} & 
    \textbf{Post-operative management} & 
    \textbf{Follow-up} \\ 
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{Non-metastatic disease}} \\ 
    \hline
    {Stage~I (T1 or T2, N0, M0)} & Surgery & None & Annual visit or telephonic consultation to investigate for symptoms. \\ 
    \hline
    Low-risk Stage~II (T3 or T4 or T4b, N0, M0) & Surgery & None & Same as Stage~I \\ 
    \cline{2-4}
    High-risk Stage~II & Surgery & Adjuvant chemotherapy & Visits every nine weeks for 36 weeks following surgery or completion of adjuvant disease. Repeat CT scan and colonoscopy three years post-surgery. Annual visits for five years after that. \\ 
    \hline
    Stage~III (T1--4, N1\nobreakdash--2b, M0) & Surgery & Adjuvant chemotherapy & Same as high-risk Stage~II \\ 
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{Metastatic disease}} \\ 
    \hline
    Resectable disease & Surgery immediately or after perioperative or conversion chemotherapy & Adjuvant chemotherapy if no perioperative or conversion chemotherapy &  \\ 
    \hline
    Unresectable disease & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} & \\
    \hline
    Performance status 0--2     & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Palliative chemotherapy} & \\ 
    \cline{1-3}
    Performance status $\geq 3$ & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Supportive management} & \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}

    \caption{TNM Staging and Management Summary}
    \end{table}
\end{document}


Can the "None" entries be included in the table?

@KelechiIgwe - Good question! :-) I noticed that the OP excluded the two "None" cells, so I kept it that way in my answer. I have no idea why the OP excluded these two cells.

Is this what you had in mind?
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\geometry{margin=1in}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \centering
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}
        \begin{tabular}{|p{2.5cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{4cm}|}
            \hline
            \textbf{Stage (TNM)} & \textbf{Initial Management} & \textbf{Post-operative Management} & \textbf{Follow-up} \\ 
            \hline
            \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Non-metastatic disease}} \\ 
            \hline
            {Stage I (T1 or T2, N0, M0)} & Surgery & None & Annual visit or telephonic consultation to investigate for symptoms. \\ %\cline{2-4}
            %& \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{} \\ 
            \hline
            Low-risk Stage II (T3 or T4 or T4b, N0, M0) & Surgery & None & Same as Stage I \\ 
            \hline
            High-risk Stage II & Surgery & Adjuvant chemotherapy & Visits every nine weeks for 36 weeks following surgery or completion of adjuvant disease. Repeat CT scan and colonoscopy three years post-surgery. Annual visits for five years after that. \\ 
            \hline
            Stage III (T1-4, N1-2b, M0) & Surgery & Adjuvant chemotherapy & Same as high-risk Stage II \\ 
            \hline
            \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Metastatic disease}} \\ 
            \hline
            Resectable disease & Surgery immediately or after perioperative or conversion chemotherapy & Adjuvant chemotherapy if no perioperative or conversion chemotherapy &  \\ 
            \hline
            %{Unresectable disease: Performance status 0-2: Performance status $\geq$ 3:} & \multicolumn{2}{|p{3cm}|}{None} Palliative chemotherapy &  \\ \cline{2-4}
            %& \multicolumn{2}{|p{3cm}|}{ Supportive management} &  \\ 
            %\hline
            Unresectable disease: & \multicolumn{2}{l}{} &  \\
            \hline
            Performance status 0--2 & \multicolumn{2}{|p{7.5cm}|}{Palliative chemotherapy} & \\ 
            \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{|p{2.5cm}|}{Unresectable disease: \newline Performance status $\geq$ 3} & \multicolumn{2}{|p{7.5cm}|}{Supportive management} & \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{TNM Staging and Management Summary}
    \end{table}
\end{document}



The table is wider than \textwidth. (You may check this by adding showframe to the list of arguments of \geometry).

Good catch. I changed the begin{tabular} line to read: \begin{tabular}{|p{2.5cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{4cm}|}.
